# Python override dictionary access methods

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding

I have a class `devices` that inherits from the dict class. devices is a dictionary of dictionaries. I would like to access its keys and values by using a method call syntax, and as well as using the normal syntax. i.e.

```
class Devices(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self['device'] = {'name':'device_name'}
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        value = self[name]
        return value
...

mydevices = Devices()
mydevice = mydevices.device #works and mydevices['device'] also works

#But what code do I need for the following?
name = mydevices.device.name 
mydevices.device.name = 'another_name'
```

I know that if I override the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods I can achieve this, but as you can see from my code I am not sure how to access a nested dictionary. 
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

thanks, labjunky

Comment: I'm surprised that you say this code works at all. It has a number of issues. Perhaps you have another class called `Devices` with (semi-)working code in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your answer is pretty much complete anyway. You can define the kind of structure you want with:

```
class Devices(dict):
    def __init__(self,inpt={}):
        super(Devices,self).__init__(inpt)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.__getitem__(name)

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.__setitem__(name,value)
```

Then a use case would be:

```
In [6]: x = Devices()

In [7]: x.devices = Devices({"name":"thom"})

In [8]: x.devices.name
Out[8]: 'thom'
```

Basically just nest your attribute-look-up dictionaries.

Comment: Is there a more general way of doing this, with out adding anything to the constructor?

Comment: @labjunky Do you mean without having the `super` call? Or do you mean you want the contents of the dictionary defined in the initialiser?

Comment: Actually its ok the way you have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to access a dictionary values use `dictionary[key]` and not `dictionary.key`. In the first case the attribute way works because you overrode `__getattr__` instead of `__getitem__`. That's why it works only for you class, but not for the inner dictionary.

Now, to access the dictionary in `__getitem__` (`__getattr__` is for attribute, like `dict.keys` where the word `keys` is the attribute) you need to be a bit careful. You need to call the `__getitem__` of the dictionary class (otherwise you'll have infinite recursion). There are two ways to achieve it. The first one will be persistent if you choose to change you object hereditary:

```
def __getitem__(self, name):
    value = super(Devices,self).__getitem__(name)
    return value
```

Another way is:

```
def __getitem__(self, name):
    value = dict.__getitem__(self, name)
    return value
```

If you still want to use attributes to access the values you'll have to replace the dictionary with your class whenever you use it (so `self['device'] = {'name':'device_name'}` will become `self['device'] = MyDictClass({'name':'device_name'})`.

---

BTW: Note that you have an error in the `__init__`. The line `self = {'device':{'name':'device_name'}}` in `__init__` actually doesn't do anything. (It puts the dictionary in the local variable `self`, but this variable disappears as soon as you exit the function.)

You should use operation that change the object itself instead. I.e.:

```
def __init__(self):
    self['device'] = {'name':'device_name'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tricky class, which is a subclass of `dict`, and whose keys can be accssed either as items (`d[k]`) or as attributes (`d.k`):

```
class Struct(dict):
     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self  # yes, it is tricky
```

The key here that the interpreter would check the `__dict__` before calling `__[gs]etattr__`, so you don't even need to override them.

Now you can do:

```
class Devices(Struct):
    pass

devices = Devices()
devices.device = Struct(name='devicename')
devices.device.name = 'anothername'
```